# Android: how to check payment status outside of the app?

Tags: android, payment, in-app-billing

Let me explain. Assume that I have android application with in-app purchases. One of the paid features leading to special web-request to the remote server. This request should be unique per each payment.

So the problem is: how the server can be ensured that this request caused by legal payment in application and not by hacker who disassembled the code? My guess is that there should be some way to check payment details on server side. Can someone explain how to implement such feature without security risks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After purchase your app sends token, order id, product id to your backend. Your server should verify transaction by chatting through [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get)
.